# Jooq MySQL compilation error with Routines generation

Tags: java, mysql, jooq

I'm using Jooq as the SQL layer in my application. It generates the code/pojos/records/routines fine but Routines.java, where MySQL procedures reside, doesn't compile because it generated a duplicated method:

Routines.java line 989:

```
/**
 * Call mmw.logMsg
 *
 * @param __Message
 * @param __Code
 * @param __Ean
 * @param __Erpnumber
 * @param __Proc
 * @throws org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException if something went wrong executing the query
 */
public static java.lang.Byte logmsg(org.jooq.Configuration configuration, java.lang.String __Message, java.lang.String __Code, java.lang.String __Ean, java.lang.String __Erpnumber, java.lang.String __Proc) {
  com.mycompany.data.routines.Logmsg f = new com.mycompany.data.routines.Logmsg();
  f.set__Message(__Message);
  f.set__Code(__Code);
  f.set__Ean(__Ean);
  f.set__Erpnumber(__Erpnumber);
  f.set__Proc(__Proc);

  f.execute(configuration);
  return f.getReturnValue();
}
```

Routines.java line 1061:

```
/**
 * Call mmw.logMsg
 *
 * @param __Message IN parameter
 * @param __Code IN parameter
 * @param __Ean IN parameter
 * @param __Erpnumber IN parameter
 * @param __Proc IN parameter
 * @throws org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException if something went wrong executing the query
 */
public static void logmsg(org.jooq.Configuration configuration, java.lang.String __Message, java.lang.String __Code, java.lang.String __Ean, java.lang.String __Erpnumber, java.lang.String __Proc) {
  com.mycompany.data.routines.Logmsg p = new com.mycompany.data.routines.Logmsg();
  p.set__Message(__Message);
  p.set__Code(__Code);
  p.set__Ean(__Ean);
  p.set__Erpnumber(__Erpnumber);
  p.set__Proc(__Proc);

  p.execute(configuration);
}
```

The error: `Routines.java:[1061,20] error: method logmsg(Configuration,String,String,String,String,String) is already defined in class Routines`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you have a procedure and a function with the exact same name and the exact same signature in your database... This isn't supported by jOOQ.

I have created a bug for this: 
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/1908

As a workaround, if you can:

- Remove/rename either the procedure or the function
- Manually patch the generated code for this case

---

Update: This issue is fixed in jOOQ 3.2

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what happened.